# Spawn outside screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Mam monster that spawn at height y 500 which is fine when the tests for the iPhone 6. But when the test for the iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 this monster spawns off the screen. How to solve it to have the same position on all sizes of screens?

Here is my code:

```
func addMonster() {

let monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "monster")
    monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: monster.size)
    monster.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.monster
    monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.naboj
    monster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    monster.position = CGPoint(x: 600 , y: 500)
    addChild(monster)

    let actionMove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: monster.size.width/2, y: 500), duration: NSTimeInterval(1.6))
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let loseAction = SKAction.runBlock() {
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size:self.size)
        let reveal = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.5)
       self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
    }
   monster.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, loseAction, actionMoveDone]))
}
```

Comment: Then don't hard code the position. Make it a function of the screen's size. You can get at this though [UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds), or through the `size` property on your scene (depending on the size of your scene).

Comment: Set its position relative to the screen. For example, `self.view.frame.size.height - 100`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically different apple devices have different screen sizes which is where your issue is. In order to fix this problem spawn in the monsters relative to screen size like so.

```
monster.position = CGPoint(x:self.view!.bounds.width / 1.1, y:self.view!.bounds.height/1.4)
```

Obviously you can change the 1.1 and 1.4 values to whatever you want to find a good height/width on the screen.

*Note you may have to change you SKAction as well to coincide with your new sprite positioning